# Rotation function weird behaviour

Tags: c++, rotation

I've been working on a rotation function. The points move sligthly to the rotation center with each cycle. It depends on a function to get the distance between the center and the point to rotate:

```
struct Vector3F
{
    float x, y, z;
};

inline float GetDistance3FX_inline(Vector3F* v1, Vector3F* v2) 
{ 
    return v1->x - v2->x; 
}

inline float GetDistance3FZ_inline(Vector3F* v1, Vector3F* v2) 
{ 
    return v1->z - v2->z; 
}
```

The actual rotation function, that **does** work:

```
void Rotate3FY(Vector3F* point, Vector3F* center, float rad)
{
    float x = GetDistance3FX_inline(point, center);
    float z = GetDistance3FZ_inline(point, center);
    point->x = x * cos(rad) - z * sin(rad) + center->x;
    point->z = z * cos(rad) + x * sin(rad) + center->z;
}
```

The function that **does not** work:

```
void Rotate3FY(Vector3F* point, Vector3F* center, float rad)
{
    point->x = GetDistance3FX_inline(point, center) * cos(rad) - GetDistance3FZ_inline(point, center) * sin(rad) + center->x;
    point->z = GetDistance3FZ_inline(point, center) * cos(rad) + GetDistance3FX_inline(point, center) * sin(rad) + center->z;
}
```

I have no clue what logical difference there is between these two. 
Thank your for any advice.

Comment: What doesn't work? Wrong results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second function when you update `point->x` you are changing the properties of `point`. Therefore when you call the same function again later during setting of `point->z`, the value of `point->x` has already changed.

```
void Rotate3FY(Vector3F* point, Vector3F* center, float rad)
{
    point->x = GetDistance3FX_inline(point, center) * cos(rad) - GetDistance3FZ_inline(point, center) * sin(rad) + center->x;
    // point is now different to what it was at the start because you just 
    // changed is x member!!!!!!!
    point->z = GetDistance3FZ_inline(point, center) * cos(rad) + GetDistance3FX_inline(point, center) * sin(rad) + center->z;
}
```

In the first function, you store the values you require in separate variables **before** modifying `point`.